# User can see other account records even though same user is not assigned to that particular group

Tags: visibility

I have created two account record ie. UK,US and Nepal. I have created three group.ie USGroup,UKGroup and NepalGroup for the account and assigned some users to every group. In sharing setting I have shared the records ie If the account equals to UK then it shares the records to UKGroup. Likewise, If account equals to US then it shares the records to USGroup. After that i have create one test user and assigned to USGroup. Now, my concern is even though i have not assigned that test user to UKGroup but this test user can see the records of UK account. I have checked everywhere whereever it is possible like in profile, permission sets and sharing setting. Please help me if i have missed some where to check for the same issue.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine why a user can see a record, you just need two steps. First, check the Organization Wide Defaults in Sharing Settings. It should be set to Private. Next, go to the Account that is visible to the user, click on the Sharing Button, click Expand List, find the user in question, and click the "Why?" link. You'll get a list of reasons why the user can see the record, such as "Owner", "Administrator", "Manager of Owner", "Account Team Member", etc. You'll need to resolve each of the sharing reasons to remove access to the account for that user.